# Finding $a_n, b_n$ so that a sequence converges in distribution to a nondegenerate random variable.

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Now, $X_1, X_2,\dots$ are iid with the same distribution as the chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom. Find $a_n$ and $b_n$ so that $a_n \left( \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_i - b_n \right)$ converges in distribution to a non-degenerate random variable.

For a $Z \sim N(0,1)$, I showed that
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{t}{1+t^2} \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2} \right) \leq P\left(\lvert Z \rvert \geq t\right) \leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{1}{t} \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}\right).
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+t} \exp\left(-\frac{t}{2} \right) \leq P\left(X_i \geq t\right) \leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \exp\left(-\frac{t}{2}\right).
\end{align*}
Also,
\begin{align*}
P \left( a_n \left( \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_i - b_n \right) \leq x \right) &= P \left( \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_i \leq \frac{x}{a_n} + b_n \right) \\
&= P\left( X_i \leq \frac{x}{a_n} + b_n \right)^n \\
&= \left[ 1 - P \left( X_i \geq \frac{x}{a_n} + b_n \right) \right]^n
\end{align*}
So, I have $P \left( a_n \left( \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_i - b_n \right) \leq x \right)$ between two nasty looking things and need to find $a_n$ and $b_n$ nice enough so that they get sandwiched by two things that tend to some normal-like thing, right? This is where I am lost. Can anyone tell me if I am going along the right direction or completely lost? Thanks!